# export phong settings in collada file

Tags: collada

I using blender 3.6, principled bsdf, and a texture as base color. When I export to "dae" file, I want that it contains phong mapping into "technique" inside "effect", not lambert. The specular value is set to 0.5 in shader, but dont show into collada file exported. I want my file like this:

```
<library_effects>
  <effect id="effect_Blue">
   <profile_COMMON>
    <technique sid="common">
     <phong>
      <ambient>
       <color>0 0 0 1</color>
      </ambient>
      <diffuse>
       <color>0.137255 0.403922 0.870588 1</color>
      </diffuse>
      <specular>
       <color>0.5 0.5 0.5 1</color>
      </specular>
      <shininess>
       <float>16</float>
      </shininess>
      <transparent opaque="A_ONE">
       <color>0 0 0 1</color>
      </transparent>
      <transparency>
       <float>1</float>
      </transparency>
      <index_of_refraction>
       <float>1</float>
      </index_of_refraction>
     </phong>
    </technique>
   </profile_COMMON>
  </effect>
 </library_effects>
```

But my collada file aways return

```
<technique sid="common">
          <lambert>
            <emission>
              <color sid="emission">0 0 0 1</color>
            </emission>
            <diffuse>
              <texture texture="human_texture-sampler" texcoord="UVMap"/>
            </diffuse>
            <index_of_refraction>
              <float sid="ior">1.45</float>
            </index_of_refraction>
          </lambert>
        </technique>
```